# How to cancel recording a macro in Vim?

Tags: vim, macros

Imagine I had recorded a macro and then I've occasionally started recording a macro into the same register. Can I interrupt the recording so that the original macro is preserved in the register?

I know that I can do `:let @b=@a` to copy the macro from register a to register b and thus preserve it but maybe there is a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you record a macro, the register is emptied first and filled as you go so it's very unlikely that there exists a built-in way to save your previous macro while you are halfway through another recording. A way that doesn't involve writing a wrapper around `q`, that is.

I and a lot of people use a temporary register (`@q`, for example) for all our one-off recordings. Maybe you should, too.

Comment: `:let @b=@q` definitely works, so it's not true that the register is cleared when you start recording a macro. And I do use q register for one-off macros. And it's most likely that I can occasionally override it.

Comment: The register is cleared on the first keypress. Will you do the `:let @b=@q` dance every time you want to record a one off macro? That's what I was hinting at with my "wrapper" idea: write a short mapping that backs up `@q` each time you hit `qq`. It's very easy. But there's no built-in "record and backup" command.

Comment: Perhaps this behavior changed, I tested it with vim 7.4 and the register is available until I press `q` the second time. So `:let @b=@a` is imho the best answer so far.

Comment: I like `qm` because I remember it with the mnemonic *re**q**ord **m**acro*.

Answer (score 16):

As noted by @Trendfischer in his comment, the current behavior of vim is not (anymore?) to empty the register on the first press of `q`.

Now, if you picked the wrong register, here is what you can do:

- do not quit the recording mode (for now),
- create an empty line,
- paste the register you are overwriting (if you're recording in the `q` register, it's `"qp`),
- now quit the recording mode (`q`)
- select the line you pasted above (without end of line mark: `0v$h`; don't use `V`)
- yank it in the register you have overwritten (`"qy` if you're using the `q` register; again: don't use the line wise copy `Y`).
- now you have your old macro back in the register and you can restart the recording of your new macro in the correct register.

Of course, with a bit of effort, you can rescue both the old and the new macro (but you have to start the process before pressing the second time the `q`): just paste what you have recorded and yank in the "new"/"right" register.